# Ogre3D with OgreBullet

Tags: ogre, bullet, bulletphysics

### Actual problem

I'm working with Ogre3D 1.7 and I am trying to build the OgreBullet library (wrapper for the Bullet 2.82 Physics librairy) but I've got some casting errors :

```
1>..\..\src\OgreBulletCollisionsRay.cpp(87): error C2664: 'OgreBulletCollisions::Object *OgreBulletCollisions::CollisionsWorld::findObject(Ogre::SceneNode *) const' : impossible de convertir le paramètre 1 de 'const btCollisionObject *' en 'Ogre::SceneNode *'
```

I didn't modify the code so I do not understand why it can't compile ? Did someone had this error ?

### EDIT (previous errors resolved):

If you have this error

```
1>..\..\src\OgreBulletCollisionsWorld.cpp(226): error C2440: 'static_cast' : impossible de convertir de 'const btCollisionObject *' en 'btCollisionObject *'
```

Try replacing **static_cast** by **const_cast** in the following lines :

```
btCollisionObject* obA = const_cast<btCollisionObject*>(contactManifold->getBody0());
btCollisionObject* obB = const_cast<btCollisionObject*>(contactManifold->getBody1());
```

Comment: well it needs to be a `const_cast`, maybe the API changed, are you sure you have the exact version of bullet that they were using?

Comment: Ok that was the solution for this error, I just managed to solve the problem with your solution. The Bullet version is maybe more recent than the one that was use for the wrapper.

Comment: Do you now something about the other error that appeared ?

    1>..\..\src\OgreBulletCollisionsRay.cpp(87): error C2664: 'OgreBulletCollisions::Object *OgreBulletCollisions::CollisionsWorld::findObject(Ogre::SceneNode *) const' : impossible de convertir le paramètre 1 de 'const btCollisionObject *' en 'Ogre::SceneNode *'

Comment: I would contact the author or whatever help forums there are at this point, I'm not sure what the intend there is. Stackoverflow isn't really a good place to solve your issue.